Donation tracking "Donationalerts"
I need to get an up-to-date list of donations so I can track users, how much they donated and what comment they left. I tried to use their API, but I always got "Unauthorized". I got a token, but using the token I couldn't get the lists of donators:
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

        // Start
        private static async Task Check()
        {

            Log.Info("accessToken Take Token");

            string clientId = "ID";
            string clientSecret = "SECRET";
            string accessToken = await GetAccessToken(clientId, clientSecret);

            Log.Info("Token: "+accessToken);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
            {
                Log.Info("accessToken Work");
                await GetDonations(accessToken);
            }
            else
            {
                Log.Info("accessToken BAD");
            }
        }

        // Take access token
        private static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string clientId, string clientSecret)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "client_id", clientId },
                    { "client_secret", clientSecret },
                    { "grant_type", "client_credentials" }
                };

                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
                var response = await client.PostAsync("https://www.donationalerts.com/oauth/token", content);
                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                // Debug
                Log.Info("accessToken API: " + responseString.ToString());


                // JSON
                try
                {
                    using (JsonDocument doc = JsonDocument.Parse(responseString))
                    {
                        JsonElement root = doc.RootElement;
                        if (root.TryGetProperty("access_token", out JsonElement tokenElement))
                        {
                            return tokenElement.GetString() ?? string.Empty; 
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (JsonException ex)
                {
                    Log.Error($"accessToken Ошибка разбора JSON: {ex.Message}");
                }
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }

        // Donats
        private static async Task GetDonations(string accessToken)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
                var response = await client.GetAsync("https://www.donationalerts.com/api/v1/alerts/donations");

                // Проверка на успешный ответ
                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error : {response.StatusCode}");
                    return;
                }

                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                Console.WriteLine("Last Donats: ");
                Console.WriteLine(responseString);

                try
                {
                    //  JSON 
                    using (JsonDocument doc = JsonDocument.Parse(responseString))
                    {
                        JsonElement root = doc.RootElement;
                        foreach (JsonElement donation in root.GetProperty("data").EnumerateArray())
                        {

                            string? username = donation.GetProperty("username").GetString();
                            decimal? amount = donation.GetProperty("amount").GetDecimal();
                            string? currency = donation.GetProperty("currency").GetString();
                            string? message = donation.GetProperty("message").GetString();

                            Console.WriteLine($"User {username}: {amount} {currency}, Message: {message}");

                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (JsonException ex)
                {
                    Log.Error($"accessToken Error JSON: {ex.Message}");
                }
            }
        }

I always get Unauthorized
I decided to try using python to track donations directly, via the web. It's about the same as opening a window where all donations are shown.
It works, but... it often turns off somewhere around once a minute. During the time while the bot is turned off, it can miss a donation and will not record anything. This also applies to the time while it was turned off, it is simply impossible to get data on donations for a certain period. For example, the donation web page somehow determines itself which donations it did not show.
import json
import socketio

da_alert_widget_token = 'TOKEN'

sio = socketio.Client(reconnection=True, reconnection_delay=5)

@sio.on('disconnect')
def on_disconnect():
    print('Disconnect')

@sio.on('reconnect')
def on_reconnect():
    print('Reconnect')

@sio.on('connect')
def on_connect():
    sio.emit('add-user', {'token': da_alert_widget_token, "type": "alert_widget"})
    print('Start')

@sio.on('donation')
def on_donation(data):
    event = json.loads(data)
    print(f'Donat: {event["username"]} - {event["amount"]} {event["currency"]}\nMessage: {event["message"]}')


sio.connect('wss://socket.donationalerts.ru:443', transports='websocket')

# Wait
sio.wait()

Please help me get data on donations. I need to somehow reliably get information either about all donations or about the last ones that were not recorded. I want to record all donations without losses.
